# How to resolve Selenium memory leak because driver.quit() was never called?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, memory, terminal

I wrote a webscraper using selenium that creates a webdriver.Chrome() when I run it. However, I forgot to add a `driver.close()` or a `driver.quit()` command when it finishes its task. As such it would seem that that caused a memory leak on my machine. Now if I run the code from terminal I get the following error message:

```
touch: /Users/work/.bash_sessions/F5AEBDAA-C7E8-4D13-A287-2003262FE8FF.historynew: No space left on device
```

Going to Storage Management I realised that I lost almost a GB of data, which is about all I had left.

I'm fairly new to selenium, it is possible to close the previously opened drivers? 
I'm using python and a mac.

Comment: Try `pkill chromedriver`

Comment: I just did. It would seem that maybe I got around 150mb back from it.

Comment: The rest is disk space, you need to remove files you don't need any more. https://www.howtogeek.com/184091/5-ways-to-free-up-disk-space-on-a-mac/

Comment: After running `pgrep chromedriver` it would seem that I no longer have a chromedriver process running which is great. Thanks a lot for your help I'll check out the link now.